# Navigation Architecture Component test app works fine on Android 8.0.0 phone but fails on Android 6.01

Tags: android

Navigation Architecture Component test app works fine on Android 8.0.0 phone but fails on Android 6.01.

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

### Error

```
     03-11 10:45:20.736 8441-8441/? E/Zygote: v2
```

03-11 10:45:20.736 8441-8441/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
03-11 10:45:21.216 8441-8441/com.cyva.warrioriamv709 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cyva.warrioriamv709, PID: 8441
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cyva.warrioriamv709/com.cyva.warrioriamv709.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at com.cyva.warrioriamv709.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141) 
        at com.cyva.warrioriamv709.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141) 
        at com.cyva.warrioriamv709.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070081
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManager.java:251)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.getDrawable(ResourceManager.java:138)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.getDrawable(ResourceManager.java:131)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:400)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:535)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:496)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:122)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:270)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:193)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141) 
        at com.cyva.warrioriamv709.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

`build.gradle module`

What more detail does this system want?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com...."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-rc02'

}


**build.gradle project**

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-rc02"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


    **main_activity.xml excerpt: fails on line 50 -** 





50        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:saveEnabled="true"
                    android:scrollY="1dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_warrior"
                    app:elevation="2dp"
                    app:insetForeground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

Comment: Generally, there is more of an error message. Can you include the entire stack trace and include what theme you are using for your Activity?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the error message (the last 'Caused by:' section):

> Caused by: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070081** at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558) at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManager.java:251) at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.getDrawable(ResourceManager.java:138) at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManager.getDrawable(ResourceManager.java:131) at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:400) at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102) at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505) at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:535) at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:496) at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:122) **at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:270)** at

Points to this being a problem with one of the icons in your `NavigationView`'s menu - specifically, it can't find a resource that it expects to be there. This means that the first thing you should do is make sure that your drawable is not only present in a version specific resource folder (such as `drawable-v23`).

Secondly, you may be using a `VectorDrawable` feature not supported on older versions of the platform. You can get consistent behavior by following the [Vector drawables backward compatibility solution documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Ian, thanks. Traced the missing vector images by their IDs in R.java. Copied from  drawable-v24 folder and put into drawable folder. Works fine now.

Comment: Great to hear! If this helped answer your question, make sure to accept the answer so that the question is removed from the queue of unanswered questions